# Qt Installer Framework: Detecting if VC++ redistributables are installed

Tags: c++, qt, installation, vcredist

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36972287/installing-vc-redistributables-in-a-qt-installer-framework-qtifw-installer), it is very helpful but it doesn't answer my question. I am using Qt Installer Frame and I want to be able to detect if VC++ redistributables are installed. Because, if they are not, the installer will install them too; and if they already are, the installer won't try to install them again. Is there a way I can do this with Qt Installer Frame?

Answer (score 0):

you have to query directly the Windows Registry.
Basically:

```
var registryVC2010x86 = installer.execute("reg", new Array("QUERY", "HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\WOW6432Node\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\10.0\\VC\\VCRedist\\x86", "/v", "Installed"))[0];
if (!registryVC2010x86) {
// VC2010 x86 redist not found: do something
}
```

I hope this will help.